# How can we run terraform scripts inside Azure functions?

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

How can we run terraform scripts inside Azure functions? We want to use durable functions so that we can deploy multiple resources in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

a) you probably cannot run TF inside Functions b) it is most likely a terrible idea. Find a proper CI/CD tool like Azure DevOps, GitHub Actions etc. They can also run parallel deployments